# npm install не работает, ошибка ecconnrefused

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

OS windows 7 64bit

Когда я ввожу команду `npm install gulp`, npm не выполняет установку.

Код ошибки:

```
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:869:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "nodemailer"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\yy
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:869:19)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yy\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

---

*ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244684/npm-install-not-work*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, ваша сеть находится за прокси-сервером. Чтобы передать данные через него, вам надо настроить *npm* при помощи следующих команд через *cmd*:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@yourproxyserver:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@yourproxyserver:port
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Или создать файл `.npmrc` по адресу `c:\@username-path@\.npmrc` с содержимым:

```
proxy=http://username:password@yourproxyserver:port/
https-proxy=http://username:password@yourproxyserver:port/
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: Возможно ли как то не светить логин и пароль в конфиге, а использовать сессию текущего пользователя?

Comment: @B.Vandyshev боюсь, что нет. по крайней мере, мне такой способ неизвестен.

Comment: Это плохо, получается нужно при каждой смене пароля нужно менять его в конфиге